# start Failed in MediaRecorder.start() while call recording in xiaomi devices

Tags: android, audio-recording

Facing issue in `recorder.start()` while recording call generates exception start failed in some devices and in some only recording one side voice and in some it is working fine.Actually not working in xiaomi devices
Below is my code.

```
                recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
                recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200);
                recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                recorder.setOutputFile(audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
                try {
                    recorder.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                recorder.start();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "In some devices", which devices?? and it could be problem of android versions, starting android 6.0 you have to allow permissions it could be that problem,

Comment: No, the issue is not about android version. Changing the audio source to MIC is working on all devices but VOICE_CALL is not working.

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: @Aditi Is audio source MIC recording otherside voice?

Comment: @bharat Ni mic is only recording the voice having app i.e. My voice only other side not working

Comment: @moorthy no solution found yet specially for mi vivo like mobile phones. Both side recording is not working in that devices.

Comment: @Aditi Did you found the solution to record other side voice ?!! Btw acr app is working fine

Comment: @Aditi thanks for the response. if any solution found please update here.am also looking on it.

Comment: @Aditi did you find any solution for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to check permissions. Call checkPermission() before initiate MediaRecorder.

```
public void checkPermission() {
    // Check for permissions
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permissionRecord = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    // If we don't have permissions, ask user for permissions
    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || permissionRecord != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        };

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                AudioRecorderActivity.this,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_RECORD
        );
    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_RECORD: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 1
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Recording permission not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```